# How do I add myself to the sudoers file?

Tags: sudo, root, vi

I attempted to add myself to the sudoers file a couple of days ago. I didn't want to have to login into root to do anything so I went into the file and inserted my name under root. Now I cannot use the sudo command even when I'm logged into root. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What distribution?

Comment: I'm using fedora server. I get this message: >>>/etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 99 <<< sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 99 sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
su root
```

Use

```
EDITOR=nano visudo
```

To fix the file yourself. Or

```
rm /etc/sudoers
```

On Debian:

```
apt-get --reinstall install sudo
```

On Fedora:

```
yum reinstall sudo
```

Then do things the right way:

```
usermod -aG sudo,wheel [user]
```

Then

```
exit
sudo whoami
```

Comment: I got this error when I typed in the line after the rm command. bash: apt-get: command not found.

Comment: Use `yum reinstall sudo`

Comment: One more question. Do I delete this post now since it got answered? Or do I just leave it?

Comment: @Sidney Upton Thats up to you. Usually you leave it for others.